# Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm' property 'outputDirectory' during up-to-date check

Tags: debugging, flutter, dart

I try debug my application but it show me this:

```
What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm' property 'outputDirectory' during up-to-date check.
Could not read path 'C:\Users\(myuser)\Documents\pop_up\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\android-arm\flutter_assets\fonts'
```

```
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option 
to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

```
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

### command

flutter build bundle --target C:\Users(myuser)\Documents\pop_up\lib\main.dart --target-platform android-arm --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --track-widget-creation --depfile C:\Users(myuser)\Documents\pop_up\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\android-arm/snapshot_blob.bin.d --asset-dir C:\Users(myuser)\Documents\pop_up\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\android-arm/flutter_assets --debug

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = 'C:\Users(myuser)\Documents\pop_up\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\android-arm/flutter_assets' (OS Error: El directorio no está vacío.
, errno = 145)

```
#0      _Directory._deleteSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:206:7)
#1      FileSystemEntity.deleteSync (dart:io/file_system_entity.dart:464:47)
#2      ForwardingFileSystemEntity.deleteSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file_system_entity.dart:72:16)
#3      writeBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle.dart:181:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      assemble (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle.dart:172:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      BundleBuilder.build (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle.dart:115:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      BuildBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_bundle.dart:119:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:407:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#12     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#13     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:397:20)
#16     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:402:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#21     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#22     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#23     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#26     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#27     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#28     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#29     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#30     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#31     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#32     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#33     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#34     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#35     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#36     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#37     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#38     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#39     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#40     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#41     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:58:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#43     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:65:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#44     main (file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#45     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:303:32)
#46     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

### flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.9.1-pre.109, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.16299.1087], locale es-AR)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1-pre.109 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision ce6dedfc0c (9 hours ago), 2019-08-20 01:03:36 -0400
    • Engine revision 10167db433
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\(myuser)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 38.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.37.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\(myuser)\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • LG H440AR • LGH440ARad51902f • android-arm • Android 5.0.1 (API 21)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Have the same issue here. Sometimes restarting the computer helped. Now when restarting computer it always gives me different folder in "could not read path..." Looks like this started happening after last flutter update

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted some files somewhere let's say on your assets folder and such a file that you are also referring on the pubspec.yaml? if so that is the reason why the application is not building, try to remove reference to deleted files (The ones that do not exist in your app's pubspec.yaml) and then run the project again to see if it builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some sort of file locking issue... When trying to open the path that is specified in output, the Windows Explorer actually returns "Access denied" so I can't access the folder and can't change security for it.
After restart the folder is accessible.

What worked for me (for now and only in that exact order):

1. Open another folder in VS Code (if you're using it). If the whole process doesn't work then restart the computer
2. "flutter clean" command
3. debug